Load multiple images one time in flutter
Let's say I have 5 images and I need to show it using Image.memory. When I load them directly at the same time it always says :Invalid image while if I load only one image, that's really fine. Is there a way to handle this. Here is the code
FutureBuilder(
                                future: imageAllLoad(message),
                                builder:
                                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                                  if (snap.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.done &&
                                      snap.hasData) {
                                    return snap.data;
                                  } else if (snap.hasError)
                                    return Text("error");
                                  else
                                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                },
                              );

imageAllLoad(BaseMessage message) async {
    await downloadAndDecryptFile(message.secureUrl ?? "");

    return Image.memory(
            valDecryptedData.value!, // I will get this value after doing await downloadAndDecryptFile(message.secureUrl ?? "");
            // errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            //   print(error.toString());
            //   return Text('Error loading image $error');
            // },
          );
  }

So I have listviewbuilder and inside listviewbuilder I load futurebuilder where imageAllLoad is a async await function to decode image. Is there a way to wait until the first image is loaded successfully and then load the next image

what exactly do you mean by "load them directly in one time "?

I need to load them at the same time when the screen opens

No, I am passing the true image, but it always says :Invalid image data when showing 5 images at the same time. but it is fine when I load it only one image, is there a way to pass the image like waiting the first image loaded succesfully and then load the second and the rest

Have you tried?- https://pub.dev/packages/cached_memory_image

provide the code you tried in question

Hi guys, I have edit my question by adding the code that I use now (I load each image using futurebuilder)

and @Aks I haven't try it, later I will. so far I still learn how to do batch load to load image one by one

you need to do it with a loop in order to show more than one image, I guess you're passing a list of decoded images

@Aiman the futurebuilder is inside the listviewbuilder which is I do looping for futurebuilder to decode images

do you mean Future.wait()?

@kpwnApps I mean load one by one image until the first one is successfully loaded and then go to next image, I think not using future.wait

you mean showing images in a sequence? like display image a for a second then b then c?

@kpwnApps yes, that's what I need, do you know how to do it

have your images urls in a list like
final imageUrls = <String>[];

on your future builder use a future like
    Future.forEach(imageUrls, (imageUrl) async{
    //get the image data first
    final bytes = await http.Client().readBytes(Uri.parse(imageUrl));

//after thats done update the state
                setState(() {
//assuming you have a global variable storing the data
                  this.imageBytes = bytes;
                });
    
//wait 5 seconds and continue with the next image
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

})
Finally change to Image.memory(this.imageBytes);

I think by replacing your function inside my imageAllLoad will not do since it doesn't have return data and I think doing setState inside imageAllLoad is not the best idea

you need the image urls first before you can get any data
